# Need a php script that matches nested opening and closing brackets and change them with tree level number?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a sript which matches nested brackets and change them with level number
Opening bracket "{" to be changed with level number and closing bracket "}" to be changed with level number with a dash before.
EG: 
level1 opening bracket "{" to be changed with "[level1]" and closing bracket "}" to be changed with "[/level1]"
level2 opening bracket "{" to be changed with "[level2]" and closing bracket "}" to be changed with "[/level2]"

Other example:

```
{{{{text{text}}}}{text text}{new text {} {another text{some other {text} here}}}}
```

and change them with level number (open+close) like this:

```
[level1]
    [level2]
        [level3]
            [level4]text
                [level5]text[/level5]
            [/level4]
        [/level3]
    [/level2]
    [level2]text text[/level2]
    [level]new text 
        [level3][/level3] 
        [level3]another text
                [level4]some other 
                    [level5]text[/level5] here
                [/level4]
        [/level3]
    [/level2]
[/level1]
```

The regex I use to find each level is this:

```
'/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x'
```

But I couldn't find a way to change brackets with corresponding level.
I would appreciate any help I can get. Thanks

Comment: Is this really a closing bracket "{"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question! I'm not sure if it's possible using regex, but this should do the job:

```
while (($closing = strpos($str, "}")) !== false) {
    //find the opening brace 
    $opening = strrpos(substr($str, 0, $closing), '{');
    //calculate level (how many opening braces are in front of the current one)
    $level = substr_count(substr($str, 0, $opening), '{') + 1;
    //replace braces by tags
    $str = substr_replace($str, '[/level' . $level . ']', $closing, 1);
    $str = substr_replace($str, '[level' . $level . ']', $opening, 1);
}

var_dump($str);
```

This gives you:

```
string(246) "[level1][level2][level3][level4]text[level5]hola[/level5][/level4][/level3][/level2][level2]text text[/level2][level2]new text [level3][/level3] [leve
l3]another text[level4]some other [level5]text[/level5] here[/level4][/level3][/level2][/level1]"
```

A more elegant way would be parsing your string as shown above but create a mulidimensional array. This array can later be printed with your `[level]` tags or used for other operations like removing single levels, replace content etc...

Comment: Works perfect for what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a recursive pattern to do that, except if you want to check if brackets are balanced before. All you need is to match brackets and to increment or decrement a variable.

```
$str = '{{{{text{text}}}}{text text}{new text {} {another text{some other {text} here}}}}';

// if needed, you can check with preg_match if curly brackets are balanced before 
// proceeding to the replacement. If not, remove it.
if ( preg_match('~\A([^{}]*(?:{(?1)}[^{}]*)*)\z~', $str) ) {
    $result = preg_replace_callback('~[{}]|[^{}]+~', function ($m) {
        static $level = 0;
        if ( $m[0] == '{' ) {
            $indent = str_repeat(' ', $level * 4);
            return $indent . '[level' . ++$level . ']' . PHP_EOL; 
        } elseif ( $m[0] == '}' ) {
            $indent = str_repeat(' ', $level * 4 - 4);
            return $indent . '[/level' . $level-- . ']' . PHP_EOL;
        } else {
            $m[0] = trim($m[0]);
            if ( empty($m[0]) ) return;
            $indent = str_repeat(' ', $level * 4 );
            return $indent . $m[0] . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }, $str);

    echo $result, PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your text in "full_string" variable, and try this:

```
$first_close = strpos($full_string, "}")
$first_split = substr($full_string, 0, $first_close);
$level = substr_count($first_split, "{");
$last_open = strrchr(first_split, "{");
$one_done = substr_replace($full_string, "[/level $level]", $first_close, 1);
$one_done = substr_replace($one_done, "[level $level]", $last_open, 1);
```

It looks for the first occurrence of the closing bracket, takes everything in front, and counts the number of closed brackets to determine the level...
Then it looks for the last occurrence of the opening bracket, and uses its location to input the level tag *(last line). Before it does, it inputs the closing tag at the position that we got in the first line. In that order, it doesn't ruin the position of the closing bracket before it gets changed to closing tag.

Improve it by making a loop that goes on untill it can't find more brackets.

- used strchr() instead of strrchr().
  The placement should be fine now.

Comment: the replacement seems to not be done correctly. My first output is: `[level 5]{{{text{text[/level 5]}}}{text text}{new text {} {another text{some other {text} here}}}}` and that's not the correct replacement